# set userdefined hostname in cloudinit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud-init

I want to know how to set hostname with current local ipv4 in it.

For example :

```
   "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
      "#cloud-config\n\n",
      "hostname: service-test-ASGTesting-$private_ipv4\n",
      "fqdn: service-test-ASGTesting-$private_ipv4.cloud-dev.test.com\n",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux hosts I use the "hostname" command as well as echo the hostname into the hosts and hostname files in /etc.

ex:

```
hostname myhostname
echo 'myhostname' > /etc/hostname
echo '127.0.0.1 myhostname' >> /etc/hosts
service hostname restart
```